# How to set system time on Kali linux?

Tags: linux, date-time, kali-linux

I am trying to set the time, using e.g.

```
date -s "11/20/2003 12:00:00"
```

however, after a few moments, the system time resets to the current time. What am I doing wrong?

NTP should not get a different time, as this is a NTP server that has no connection to any other NTP server.

Answer (score 7):

if you have the npt > `apt-get install ntp`. You must stopping or uninstalling the service doesn't help.

```
timedatectl set-ntp 0 (off > sync disabled)
or     
timedatectl set-ntp 1 (on > sync enabled)
```

**Disable with `timedatectl set-ntp 0`** then you can change date:

```
date --set 1998-11-02 
date --set 21:08:00
```

see [Maintaining Time on Debian - Datetime and NTP client and server](http://www.kossboss.com/linux---maintaining-time-on-debian---datetime-and-ntp-client-and-server)

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:

```
# Find your timezone
$ timedatectl list-timezones
$ timedatectl set-timezone "YOUR-TIMEZONE"
```

Method 2:

```
$ timedatectl set-time "HH:MM:SS"
```

NOTE: 24 - Hours Time Format

**TIP: Make sure to synchronize your system clock (RTC) with the hardware clock as well.**

```
$ hwclock -w
```